# Compile PJSIP 2.5 Library for all architectures

Tags: ios, makefile, build, voip, pjsip

To compile PJSIP library for iPhone device, I am using this code

```
make distclean && make clean
ARCH='-arch arm64' ./configure-iphone --enable-opus-codec
make dep
make
```

This code allows me to install my app for single architecture only.
To compile pjsip for all the architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386, x86_64), Which command or tool I can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to compile for all devices.

1. compile for all devices separately
2. merge with lipo

eg.

`-create /libsrtp-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a /libsrtp-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a -output output_file_name`

then use `output_file_name.a` as a universal library for all device and simulator

to check supported architecture : `output_file_name.a`

`lipo -info name_of_static_lib`

`output :
/libsrtp-universal-apple-darwin_ios.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64`

[Compile PJSIP 2.5 Library for all archietectures](http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/07/10/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-4/)

Thanks

Comment: You can get all answer on this link https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Comment: I tried to compile first for architecture armv7s, after that compiled for arm64, like this I continued for all architecture compilation. All architecture compiled successfully, but problem is that last compiled library only works fine other framework library compilation result gets overridden. And compilation result appears at path : /MyApps/2.2/2.2_original2/pjsip-apps/build/output. Please help me if you know proper way for compilation. Your help will be really very appreciated.

Comment: just compile for each architecture eg. armv7s and keep it in a separate folder, similarly for other also.

finally pick common .a file from each architecture and then merge by lipo -create <seperate architecture.a file path separated by space> -output <path of the output file with name> command. do it like this

eg.
lipo -create libSignatureLibary_armv6.a libSignatureLibary_armv7.a libSignatureLibary_i368.a -output libSignatureLibary.a

Comment: Finally I created all .a files compatible with all architectures. But still when I run for simulator , xCode can not find the library and gives errors. Is there any settings need to change inside "Build Setting"?

Comment: then just set the path of **"pjsip-include"** in **“Header Search Paths”:**

Comment: yes. I created universal libraries. checked with xcrun command. Also they are showing availability for all the architecture. In "Header Search Paths", added path as per given in link. And set "Build Active Architecture" - No. But still creates errors.

Comment: Can you just let me know the issue you are facing??

Comment: Linker errors are generating. For Ex:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 _pj_get_sys_info", referenced from:
 _sip_startup in PJSIP_UA_Layer.o

Comment: Try with this setting: Build active architecture Only(Yes)
valid architecture: i386 arm64

Answer (score 6):

```
--- One Way to build PJSIP libraries --- test with pjsip 2.6

//Updated for XCode 8. 

Building PJSIP
$ cd /Users/ravimalviya/Developer/Dev2/trunk

//If you want to specify the minimum supported iOS version
//export MIN_IOS="-miphoneos-version-min=8.0"

Compile Library and Build For Default iPhone 4 use armv7 architecture
$ ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make

Build For iPhone 5, use armv7s architecture
$ ARCH='-arch armv7s' ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make

Build For iPhone 5s, use arm64 architecture
$ ARCH='-arch arm64' ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make

Build For Simulator, use i386 architecture
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
ARCH="-arch i386" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone
make dep && make clean && make

Build For Simulator, use x86_64 architecture
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
ARCH="-arch x86_64" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone
make dep && make clean && make

The compilation result
pjlib/lib       
pjlib-util/lib
pjmedia/lib
pjsip/lib
pjnath/lib
third_party/lib
Note add into project..

Combine resulting archtecture(arm64,armv7,armv7s,i386, x86_64) supported library .a file.

//goto directory where you collect all build library. create folder name arm64, armv7s, armv7, i386, x86_64 and put all library respectivly. each having only one arch supported library file.
//rename file in all these 5 folders it's a easy way to make universal library.
//Also create folder named unified where all unversal library will create.

$ export LIB_NAME="libg7221codec.a"
$ lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

//-arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME means support armv7s get library from directory armv7s/$LIB_NAME and $LIB_NAME file name that only support armv7s.
//-arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME ............
//-arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME ............
//-arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME ..............
//-arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME ..............
//unified/$LIB_NAME is directory where unversal library will build using lips. with same name $LIB_NAME that export. do it same.

//check which arch you lib is supporting
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info unified/$LIB_NAME

$ export LIB_NAME="libgsmcodec.a"
$ lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME
$ export LIB_NAME="libilbccodec.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpj.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjlib-util.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia-audiodev.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia-codec.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia-videodev.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjnath.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsdp.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsip-simple.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsip-ua.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsip.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsua.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsua.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libpjsua2.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libresample.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libspeex.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libsrtp.a"
$ .....same as above in lipo......
$ export LIB_NAME="libyuv.a"
$ lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

Note: Unversal libraries you can add into your project and also mention in library search path.

//In order to use the pjsip libraries, we need to include folder that ahve header files that access .a files. Naturally, the header files are located in:
pjlib/include
pjlib-util/include
pjmedia/include
pjnath/include
pjsip/include

Note: do't add into project..buz you can not import like import <pjsip-lib/pjsip.h>
so just place these folder into project directory where ever you want but mention in header search path.

Enjoy (:)
```

Comment: Nice explanation really aapreiciate

Answer (score 2):

We wrote a cocoapod that will create a static library that you can include in your project. For the moment you can only use it in an Objective C cocoapod environment. We are working on a version that will create a dynamic library so it can be used with Swift.

Please check it out on:

https://github.com/VoIPGRID/Vialer-pjsip-iOS

We've made an open source wrapper that makes integrating PJSIP in your iOS project a lot easier:

https://github.com/VoIPGRID/VialerSIPLib

Comment: Can I ask you to review [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the merge like this as posted

**lipo -create**  /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/x86_64/**libgsmcodec-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a** /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/i386/**libgsmcodec-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a** /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/armv7s/**libgsmcodec-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a** /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/armv7/**libgsmcodec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a** /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/arm64/**libgsmcodec-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a** **-output** /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/universal/**libgsmcodec-universal-apple-darwin_ios.a**

finally test it

**lipo -info** /My\ Project/pjsip-universal/libgsmcodec-universal-apple-darwin_ios.a

output: 
Architectures in the fat file: /My Project/pjsip-universal/libgsmcodec-universal-apple-darwin_ios.a are: **i386 armv7s armv7 x86_64 arm64**

Once you generate the universal architecture:

Follow this link to add in you project from this line in link

**Adding the header files into the project**

[how to add in project](http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/07/10/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-4/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes Exactly! but Folders like arm64, armv7, armv7s, i386, x86_64, universal, pjsip-include are not generating. Is there any specific command to manage directory wise ? Right now all these .a files are generated directly under third_party/lib. I know only your help can make me out of this.

Comment: I have create these folder separately for different architecture by collecting .a from these location as per given in above link

**"pjsip_include"** folder contains header files for library. for more about it follow above link.
 
**"universal"** folder contains the universal library for every .a file created by me. 

In each architecture there will be 19 Items. plz follow the link  that will describe from where you have to copy the .a file for each architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this script to build pjsip for my archs.

I am running it in the *pjsip* root folder, it creates a ***uni*** folder containing the resulting libraries which I then link/add into my project.

```
#!/bin/bash

ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64"
mkdir -p uni

echo "Compiling..."
for arch in $ARCHS
do
  echo $arch
  echo "=================================="
  echo
  ARCH="-arch $arch" ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make
  echo "Done."
  echo
done

RESULT_PATHS="pjlib/lib pjlib-util/lib pjmedia/lib pjsip/lib pjnath/lib third_party/lib"
for path in $RESULT_PATHS
do
  echo $path
  for file in `ls $path/*-armv7-*`
  do
    library=`echo $file | sed "s/-armv7-\(.*$\)//g"`
    library_tail=`echo $file | sed "s/.*-armv7-//g"`
    lipo -arch armv7 $library-armv7-$library_tail -arch armv7s $library-armv7s-$library_tail -arch arm64 $library-arm64-$library_tail -create -output $library.a
    cp -vi $library.a uni
  done
done
```