# How to build and integrate pjsip 2.5.5 for both simulator and device in my iOS project?

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

How to build and integrate pjsip 2.5.5 for both sinulator and device in my project?

I got error:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing pjsip for all devices and simulators, it should be compiled for every architecture and all that libraries should be combined using -lipo command. Please find this link. It may help you.

[Compile for all architecture seperately](http://www.sillycodes.com/2014/09/compiling-pjsip-for-different.html)

[Combine library for all architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38184950/6343980)

Comment: I want to compile for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 also specially for x86_64 etc, can you please provide code for that. I have build for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 but can not able to build for x86_64. thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to compile with following commands: (1) export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer  (2)ARCH="-arch i386" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2" ./configure-iphone
(3) make dep && make clean && make.    if you still get the same error clean and try again.     NOTE:
Make sure your selected xcode path is same as DEVPATH.
To check selected xcode path
xcode-select -p

To switch xcode path
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develo

Comment: bro I need to compile it for x86_64 architecture, I know above such things, and when you got answer edit your answer and I will check your answer up. Every problem comes with new solutions and yup always reward. :) if need help about pjsip in future feel free to ask, we are indians always ready for help.

Comment: Try to compile with following commands: (1) export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms‌​/iPhoneSimulator.pla‌​tform/Developer (2)ARCH="-arch x86_64" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2" ./configure-iphone (3) make dep && make. If issue occurs again, please write about which pjsip version you are compiling.